# Is it a valid method of Proof?

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof

Sorry for asking a trivial question.

If I have to proof a statement like this:

$tan A tan B + tan B tan C + tan C tan A = 9$, then prove that the triangle ABC is equilateral.

My proof:
If the triangle is equilateral then each angle must be equal to $\frac{π}{3}$,
As $tan(\frac{π}{3}) = √3$, 
So 3+3+3=9, hence proved.

Is it a valid method of proof. 
If not, please tell how to tackle these problems.

Comment: You proved that if $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral then $\tan a\tan b+\tan b\tan c+\tan c\tan a=9$ while you need to prove the different direction. Btw, if it is triangle $ABC$ then those 3 are the side of the triangle and not the angles, you need to give the angles different names

Comment: I can prove something from either direction, right? The triangle is ABC with vertices A, B, and C and sides a, b and c. Angles are also A, B, C, is it wrong?

Comment: the name of the triangle is always goes by the sides, and the sides are not the angles

Comment: I fear you are mistaken @Holo, triangle is named by its vertices which are also the names of angles written in capital letters while sides are written in small letters.

Comment: so it is probably a cultural thing, because this is how I learned it. Anywho the main point is that you proved one side, you need to proved the other side as well